# Subset rows using data from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large data set that i read from a CSV into a dataframe with a 1s freq datetime index. The df is approx 2.5gb when loaded. Most of the data is stored as np.float32.  During the acquisition of the source data it is sometimes sampled at 16hz, but the CSV is indexed with 1 second rows, so the burst array data is stored in the form CH[0], CH[1]...CH[15] along the single second row. So CH0 represents time zero, CH1 represent time + 0.0625s etc.  I want to sanitize this data so that there is a new row for each sub second measurement. So basically all the data from that measurement in the same column over 16 rows rather than 16 columns in 1 row. There are hundreds of these burst channels in the dataset, but a simplified version of the data during a burst period (changed to 4hz for simplicity) would look like below. The data returns to NaN after the burst acquisition is over:

I don't know where to start with this :(

```
                      CH0  CH1  CH2  CH3
TIME
2019-02-09 12:53:06   29   12   43   10
2019-02-09 12:53:07   56   15   77   88
2019-02-09 12:53:08   82    9   95   19
2019-02-09 12:53:09   13   13   79    1
2019-02-09 12:53:10   35   87   77   37
2019-02-09 12:53:11   53    9    5    9
2019-02-09 12:53:12   25   63   78   70
2019-02-09 12:53:13   23   62   41   22
2019-02-09 12:53:14   21   52   10   82
```

I would like the data to look more like this (first 2 seconds shown):

```
                        CH0  CH1  CH2  CH3
TIME
2019-02-09 12:53:06.00   29   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:06.25   12   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:06.50   43   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:06.75   10   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:07.00   56   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:07.25   15   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:07.50   77   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:07.75   88   Nan  Nan  Nan
2019-02-09 12:53:08.00   82   Nan  Nan  Nan
```

It doesn't matter if the data is copied into a new column such as df['CH'] or if CH0 is reused. I would then drop the CH1 etc columns.

EDIT:

I tried the provided answer, but i have hit a snag when 'TIME' is already defined as my index. I get a key error at line#20 df1['TIME'] = df['TIME'], I get this I assume TIME no longer exists as a column, so i tried:

`df1.index = df.index`

That didn't work. Can someone suggest a change to the code based on index already being in datetime. My current complete code, including how i am producing the proof of concept data is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt 

#Set up df to be representative of the real data, time indexed to 1s.
date_today = dt.datetime.now()
time = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + dt.timedelta(0.0001), freq='s')

np.random.seed(seed=9)
data0 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(time))
data1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(time))
data2 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(time))
data3 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(time))
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': time, 'CH0': data0, 'CH1':data1, 'CH2':data2, 'CH3':data3 })
df = df.set_index('TIME')
df.index = df.index.round('s')
print(df)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['TIME'] = (df['TIME'])
df1['CH'] = df['CH0']

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['TIME'] = (df['TIME'] + dt.timedelta(milliseconds=250))
df2['CH'] = df['CH1']

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['TIME'] = (df['TIME'] + dt.timedelta(milliseconds=500))
df3['CH'] = df['CH2']

df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df4['TIME'] = (df['TIME'] + dt.timedelta(milliseconds=750))
df4['CH'] = df['CH3']

result = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], ignore_index=True)
#result.sort_values(by=['TIME'])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add milliseconds and concatenate data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df1['CH0'] = df['CH0']

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=250))
df2['CH0'] = df['CH1']

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=500))
df3['CH0'] = df['CH2']

df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df4['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=750))
df4['CH0'] = df['CH3']

result = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4])
result.sort('time')
```

If your column is already datetime you can omit pd.to_datetime.
Please remember to `import datetime`.
In concat you can use `ignore_index=True`.
but I think will be faster first set time index.
Probably you can loop or even make lambda with that code if you want it more dry.